Unable to fix layout issue in android SDK 35

In the image attached, list view scroll over TitleBar if compile SDK and target SDK is 35.
How to limit it under TitleBar.
But if i use SDK 34, then its OK.
Used below code but no luck
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
        activity.getWindow().setAttributes(new WindowManager.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_NEVER));
    }


you need to support Window insets, some article also HERE, or at least use windowOptOutEdgeToEdgeEnforcement flag
